# Comment edit button still enabled/available after edit period elapsed

Tags: feature-request, comments

Right now, for 5 minutes, you're able to edit any comment:

[image]

Even after the 5 minute grace period, this edit button still works/is enabled:

[image]

The user is mislead to believing they can edit their comment, and spend time improving/updating their comment, only to recieve this message:
[image]

For larger comments, this can be quite frustrating. I'd like to recommend some client side checks that when the comment reaches 5 minutes old, the edit button is removed from the client side (Or as soon as they hit the button, if it's more than 5 minutes old, display the error message). Additionally, if the user hits the edit button before the 5 minute period, I recommend a server side grace period (Somewhere between 1-5 more minutes) to allow the user some additional time to finish their edit.

While the duplicate mentions part of what I'm proposing, it does not going into detail about server side grace periods, nor how the edit button should work at 5 minutes (I offer a few different solutions). I find it difficult to justify editing the other post to add my suggestions to that post in order to make it resemble an exact duplicate (As stated in my comment below)

Comment: I think this can be both considered a bug, and a feature-request. Also: This post goes into more detail, so not an exact duplicate.

Comment: Details are not reason enough, they can just be added to the original report. And it's not a bug, it's the intended behavior. The vote buttons are also not gone or disabled on your own posts, even though you can't vote on them, for example.

Comment: @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard I'm not going to edit another users post to add additional suggestions that he may or may not want added to the feature-request.

Comment: SE focus is content, not who posted it. That's why they let anyone suggest edits, and any user with enough not-so-high reputation to edit without any review process.

Comment: Also, while it is a gray area to edit others' posts to add more info on regular (main) sites because it could change the meaning, here on Meta it's an accepted and expected practice.

Comment: @Shadow I would have preferred closing the earlier one as a duplicate, as by itself the question looks like a long-ago problem that may have been solved. Also, the target isn't very clearly phrased.

Comment: This is **NOT** an exact duplicate. Sigh

Comment: @Sonic there's no "problem". The "issue" is that the comment edit link won't go away or become disabled automatically after 5 minutes.